# jQuery Dom manipulation undefined error on console while traversing dom

Tags: jquery

on the console is printed undefined, despite the fact that items has 3 elements in my case. How to solve?

```
var groups = $('div .card');
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  var itemGroup = "<ItemGroup><GroupName>" + $(groups[i]).find('button').text() + "</GroupName>";
  var items = $(groups[i]).find('.form-control');
  for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    console.log($(items[j]).find('input').val());
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card"><div class="card-header" id="Group101"><h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Group10" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Group1</button></h5></div><div id="Group10" class="collapse in" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="true" style=""><div class="card-body"><div class="form-group"><em>Desc</em>  <input class="form-control field" name="Default1" pattern="[1..9]" data-type="int" value="100"><br><br></div><div class="form-group"><em>Desc</em>  <input class="form-control field" name="Default1" pattern="[1..9]" data-type="int" value="100"><br><br></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selector `$('div.card')` to select all divs with class `card`. Use `each` to loop thru the divs.

```js
$('div.card').each(function(i, o) {
  var itemGroup = "<ItemGroup><GroupName>" + $(o).find('button').text() + "</GroupName>";

  $(o).find('.form-control').each(function(k, v) {
    console.log($(v).val());     //No need to find() | .form-control is already the input.
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="Group101">
    <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Group10" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Group1</button></h5>
  </div>
  <div id="Group10" class="collapse in" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="true" style="">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group"><em>Desc</em> <input class="form-control field" name="Default1" pattern="[1..9]" data-type="int" value="100"><br><br></div>
      <div class="form-group"><em>Desc</em> <input class="form-control field" name="Default1" pattern="[1..9]" data-type="int" value="100"><br><br></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```